# Using pushViewController on UIViewController does not push new controller on stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, tdd

I am writing tests to verify that a new view controller of a certain type is pushed on a navigation controller's stack when a certain action is made. However, I'm finding that calling `pushViewController` does not result in my `UIViewController`s list of view controllers being updated nor the top one being the newly pushed controller.

Here's an abbreviated version of my test class:

```
#import "RRViewController.h"
#import "RestroomDetailsViewController.h"

@implementation RRViewControllerTests
{
    RRViewController *viewController;
    ...
    UINavigationController *navigationController;
}

- (void)setUp
{
    [super setUp];

    viewController = [[RRViewController alloc] init];
    ...
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
}

...

- (void)testSelectingRestroomPushesNewViewController
{
    [viewController userDidSelectRestroom];

    UIViewController *currentTopViewController = navigationController.topViewController;

    XCTAssertFalse([currentTopViewController isEqual:viewController], @"New view controller should be pushed onto Navigation Controller stack.");

    XCTAssertTrue([currentTopViewController isKindOfClass:[RestroomDetailsViewController class]], @"New view Controller should be an RestroomDetailsViewController.");
}
```

And here is the `RRViewController` class with that `userDidSelectRestroomn` method called on `viewController`:

```
#import "RestroomDetailsViewController"

...

- (void)userDidSelectRestroom
{
    RestroomDetailsViewController *nextViewController = [[RestroomDetailsViewController alloc] init];

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
}
```

The issue is that both of my tests are failing. Taking a look at `navigationController.viewControllers` in the `RRViewControllerTests` test class after `userDidSelectRestroom` is called shows:

```
<__NSArrayI 0x7ffaf9d37020>(
    <RRViewController: 0x7ffaf9eba420>
)
```

i.e. just the original root `RRViewController`.

Any thoughts as to why the new `RestroomDetailsViewController` is not pushed onto `navigationController`'s stack?

Comment: Have you tried testing it without animations? It may not be added to the stack until the animations complete.

Comment: Just tried it - test passed!